# where to configure AspectJ in Android Studio gradle plugin

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am attempting to create an Android Studio gradle plugin.

I am employing Jake Whartons `Hugo` plugin as a guide.

The plugin I am developing differs from Hugo in the folloiwng ways:-

1). I do not wish to use a marker annotation
2). I want to develop my plugin using `Java` and not `Groovy`

However in all other respects my plugin is very similar, e.g. it uses
`AspectJ` to weave into any Android apps and/or libraries.

I believe all I need to develop are the plugin module and the associated runtime module.
What I do not understand is why both the Hugo plugin and runtime modules have the folloiwng (gradle) configuartion
e.g. starting from "`JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompiler`"

**hugo-runtime (build.gradle)**

```
import org.aspectj.bridge.IMessage
import org.aspectj.bridge.MessageHandler
import org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.10'
    compile project(':hugo-annotations')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompiler
    javaCompile.doLast {
        String[] args = [
                "-showWeaveInfo",
                "-1.5",
                "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                "-bootclasspath", android.bootClasspath.join(File.pathSeparator)
        ]

        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
        new Main().run(args, handler)

        def log = project.logger
        for (IMessage message : handler.getMessages(null, true)) {
            switch (message.getKind()) {
                case IMessage.ABORT:
                case IMessage.ERROR:
                case IMessage.FAIL:
                    log.error message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.WARNING:
                case IMessage.INFO:
                    log.info message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.DEBUG:
                    log.debug message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**hugo-plugin (Groovy Class - apply method)**

```
   @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        def hasApp = project.plugins.withType(AppPlugin)
        def hasLib = project.plugins.withType(LibraryPlugin)
        if (!hasApp && !hasLib) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("'android' or 'android-library' plugin required.")
        }

        final def log = project.logger
        final def variants
        if (hasApp) {
            variants = project.android.applicationVariants
        } else {
            variants = project.android.libraryVariants
        }

        project.dependencies {
            debugCompile 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT'
            // TODO this should come transitively
            debugCompile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.6'
            compile 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT'
        }

        project.extensions.create('hugo', HugoExtension)

        variants.all { variant ->
            if (!variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
                log.debug("Skipping non-debuggable build type '${variant.buildType.name}'.")
                return;
            } else if (!project.hugo.enabled) {
                log.debug("Hugo is not disabled.")
                return;
            }

            JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompile
            javaCompile.doLast {
                String[] args = [
                        "-showWeaveInfo",
                        "-1.5",
                        "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                        "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                        "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                        "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                        "-bootclasspath", project.android.bootClasspath.join(File.pathSeparator)
                ]
                log.debug "ajc args: " + Arrays.toString(args)

                MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
                new Main().run(args, handler);
                for (IMessage message : handler.getMessages(null, true)) {
                    switch (message.getKind()) {
                        case IMessage.ABORT:
                        case IMessage.ERROR:
                        case IMessage.FAIL:
                            log.error message.message, message.thrown
                            break;
                        case IMessage.WARNING:
                            log.warn message.message, message.thrown
                            break;
                        case IMessage.INFO:
                            log.info message.message, message.thrown
                            break;
                        case IMessage.DEBUG:
                            log.debug message.message, message.thrown
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Isnt this just required in the hugo-runtime module as this is where the AspectJ is located?